# Anti-debug that can broke programm links (branches)?

Tags: ida, debugging, anti-debugging

I met the unknown (for me) method of anti-debugging today, while debugging in IDA Pro. This method delete fast all branches in file and the programm will look similar like on the image:[image]

Also many parts of code became unrecognized bytes, but I can fix this with Make Code command (only code, not branches). What it can be and how I can bypass this? The programm works fine after that, but I can't use breakpoints.

Comment: The flow looks fairly obvious for your example. If IDA isn't drawing the lines between the blocks that looks like an IDA bug. I can't see how an anti-debug mechanism would trigger this.

Comment: have you checked the graph color settings or a customised desktop setting etc may be the color of background and arrow colors are same